# Authenticate .net client with On-Site Sharepoint 2013

Tags: .net, authentication, sharepoint-2013

I want to authenticate a Windows User via a C# console application connecting to an on-site (but not local!) Sharepoint 2013 server.

It is easy, in a browser, to browse to the Sharepoint website and authenticate using the user's Windows credentials.  However, I can't tell what technology to use to replicate this behavior from my own console app.

Lots of references to connecting to Sharepoint Online using class SharePointOnlineCredentials.  However, I want to do this without involving Azure or any third party (just like the browser presumably does), and my Sharepoint website is on-site, not 'Online'.

Ultimately, I want to use the REST interface from C#.

Which technologies do I need to use?

Comment: you really need to use the respective technology to authenticate. why do you not want to do this??

Comment: My Sharepoint website is not 'Online' - it's 'on site'.  It seems that SharePointOnlineCredentials is not appropriate.  I've clarified my question now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to simply populate the Credentials property of the .Net request object.  I'm so new to C# I didn't realize this, and I suspect no one realized that I didn't realize.